# What gestures make sense in a GIS application?

Tags: interface

Have been testing [Microsoft Beta APIs for kinect](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/default.aspx) with the [kinect Toolkit](http://kinecttoolkit.codeplex.com/). To create an appliation that catch a users gesture is very easy. As a GIS developer it feels like it would integrate perfectly with [ESRI ArcGIS for WPF](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/wpf/index.html), to build for example kiosk applications where a user can interact with a map. What gestures would make sense for a user to navigate a map?

Comment: Great question! I think we can keep it software-independent.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's not about the technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent publication from IJHG (open access) might be of some help:

***['Web GIS in practice X: a Microsoft Kinect natural user interface for Google Earth navigation'](http://www.ij-healthgeographics.com/content/10/1/45)***

But I'm really waiting for somebody to integrate [**MYO**](https://getmyo.com/) into my GIS desktop!

Answer (score 3):

These are quite good (and tested, as mentionned in the video), made with the WPF toolkit: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj3z6bhcSsM

One caveat about the Kinect is that it uses full body gestures: the skeleton detection from the official Kinect SDK is very innacurate if it can see only part of your body (e.g. sitting at your desk), however if you need that, [OpenNI](http://www.openni.org) instead of the official SDK could be helpful).

Comment: Thanks, interesting video. Made me realize that when  navigating a 2D or a 3D map, probably need different sets of gestures.